# VS2010 WF Designer always hang when scrolling to a bigger nest of process activities

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

I logged few reports to Microsoft Forum and Microsoft Connect. However, they didn't give me an exact feedback...

I am facing trouble to read XAML file with VS2010 Workflow Designer. I already formatted twice with clean Windows 7 SP1 x64 Enterprise OS and with the KBs. So did the VS2010 SP1 Ultimate x86 with all the KBs (as well as NET4.0 KBs).

My hardware is pretty fair good with Core 2 Duo T9400 with 4GB memory size. The only drawback I believe is the display interface - Mobile Intel 4 Family Series Chipset. I have 2 colleagues using the same model like mine... They never encountered any problem with scrolling/editing the XAML inside the VS2010 WF Designer...

That is a very big question for me... Probably the only way to explain is because my hardware has problem...

Has anyone of you facing the problem like I did?

=======

HOLY COW!

FINALLY! SOLVED!

Do you know why??? If you are using HP laptop/PC, please do not install the HP ProtectTools Security Manager Suite!

This is my 3rd format with Windows 7 SP1 Enterprise x64 with default drivers installation.
The next thing I did is just installing VS2010 SP1 Ultimate x86 first.
Amazingly, XAML doesn't crash anymore!
So, I installed the driver from one to one and tested out with the VS2010 SP1.

AND **FOUND THE CULPRIT!!! HP ProtectTools Security Manager Suite!**

This issue has been bugging me 1 week time =.=' I never do my work whole week just to debug this issue!

It has nothing to do with Microsoft. But with VS2010SP1, it crashes with HP ProtectTools Security Manager Suite! I cannot use finger sign-in anymore :/ Sigh!

Comment: Have you already tried [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871) KB? It fixes lots of WPF issues and I've read a few times that it takes care of some Workflow Designer's issues too.

Comment: Yea, this KB is installed into NET40 Client Profile and NET40 Extended.